# stm32cubeide headless build returns No Project matched error

Tags: c++, rtos, stm32cubeide

I am trying to build a c++ project using the linux based exclipse build tool stm32cubeide. I am executing this from the root directory where all of the code exists which throws this error.

> stm32cubeide --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data . -build MyTestProject

- WARNING: No Project matched "MyTestProject". Skipping...

Answer (score 1):

You should be running the command inside the workspace directory and not the project directory.

If you want to be running the command inside the project directory, you could create a temporary build folder (for instance under `C:\STM32CubeIDE_headlessBuilds`) and run the following command (replace projectFolderPath by the project folder path):

```
stm32cubeidec.exe --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data "C:\STM32CubeIDE_headlessBuilds" -import "projectFolderPath" -build MyTestProject
```

- The `-data` option is used to specify the location of the workspace
  folder.
- The `-import` option is used to specify the path of the
  project to import.